# Save common assets in window object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a HTML based page with JavaScript (React) components loaded from separate files, and rendered in separate root containers on the page. Currently I'm including ReactDOM and React in every component to make this work.

Is there a way to first load a JavaScript on top of the page that saves React and ReactDOM into the window object, so that the component later rendered on the page can use it?

That way I do not need to include it in every file.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What do you mean by "That way I do not need to include it in every file."?

Comment: I want React as a common (for the page) dependency. I do not want to include React in every component.

Comment: Why not? It's literally one line of code `import { React } from 'react';` or something like that.

Comment: because the files gets much bigger. its bloat, and its not good for pagespeed.

Comment: Hogwash. Any decent minifier will reduce that code to a few tens of bytes, and the browser caches `import`s so it doesn't need to import the same file multiple times. Sounds like premature optimization to me. Measure the "bloat" caused by importing React multiple times.

Comment: The componens are in separate files, that are lazy loaded on the page, so the library gets included in each and every file. I cannot be three shakened bywebpack. It's something in the ballpark of 100KB extra for every component.